# Getting a radio button ID with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("#MyInputBox").keyup(function () {
        var nextChk = $(this).next(":radio:checked").attr('id'));
        alert(nextChk);
    });
});
```

What is the correct way to say "Get the ID of the next checkbox which is checked" Am I even close?

Comment: You're asking about DOM traversal, but you're not providing your DOM.

Comment: @amnotiam : Didn't bother providing a DOM as it's a generic question :) Should have mentioned the assumption I suppose.

Comment: @RawryLions: Well, no DOM traversal question is generic. Some people try to use `.next()` when the elements aren't actually siblings (like when they're nested in ancestors that are siblings). So it always depends on the actual markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Assuming*** your radio inputs are all siblings, you'd need to use `.nextAll()`, and then narrow down to the first match.

```
$(this).nextAll(":radio:checked:first").attr('id');
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
```

---

Or you could technically use `.nextUntil()` with `.next()`.

```
$(this).nextUntil(":radio:checked").next().attr('id');
```

---

Also, I see that you're asking about checkboxes, but your code uses `:radio`, so I guess I don't know which one you actually want.

Comment: Works perfectly, cheers. Still getting used to jQuery. I'll mark it as answered once my time limit is up :)